# How do I delete a photo from android phone using BridgeIt?

Tags: android, web-applications, android-camera, mobile-website

I hav been playing with new BridgeIt release.  I can upload photos great, but does anybody know how to make the web application delete or remove the photo last taken?  I know the user can go into photo and delete it manually but that is extra steps.  PhoneGap has camera cleanup method which I liked.  Is there something similar for bridge it?

Answer (score 0):

Once the photo is uploaded, it's up to the web application to store or delete it. In the case of the BridgeIt demo, photos are uploaded and then automatically deleted after a period of time.  In terms of device storage, the photos are captured to temporary files on the device and then uploaded, so will be cleaned up automatically by the operating system.